# Visual Studio 2012 no longer debugs unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, com, visual-studio-debugging

Recently my Visual Studio 2012 lost the ability to debug unmanaged code.  What I have is a C# project which references a C++ COM module.  It uses a interop library that I created using tlbimp.exe.  The COM module is registered, and the C# project has 'Enable native code debugging' checked.  I'm using Windows 7 (current on updates) as the operating system and this project is set to x86 for both the C# and C++.  This is a practice that I've been doing for years, and debugging has never been a problem.

When the project loads, the breakpoints are disabled with the message 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document.'  When I load the Modules window the COM module is not in the list and I cannot find how to add it.

Is there a recent update or something that could have caused this problem?  What can I do to make this work again?

Comment: Have you enabled asm code file generation for the dll c++ compiler? Maybe it needs an asm file to debug on if it is not CLR compliant?

Comment: If you can't the module in the Modules debugger window then you can never debug it.  Verify that other native DLLs appear in the list, like kernel32.dll and ntdll.dll.  Consider a simple mistake like accidentally switching to the Release configuration.

Comment: `Clean your solution` and then `rebuild` application. this helped me a couple of times.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - This is not C++.NET; it is completely unmanaged code.

Comment: @HansPassant - It is definitely in Debug mode, and the project files (.vcproj, .vcxproj) have not been altered in years.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi - Been there, done that, several times.

Comment: The modules list does contain unmanaged modules kernel32.dll and ntdll.dll.

Comment: Your C# project have some option like "debug only my code"? or soo enabled? Once it was my problem, and uncheking it I could debug my "external" code.

Comment: Make sure that the COM object you are trying to get is the COM object you think it is. The description makes it sound like the COM object you expect is not the COM object being invoked. Otherwise, set a break point in your COM object, and run your solution in Visual Studio. When it loads up the COM object, the break point will then become active and then be hit.